# UILabel Multiline Text Scale Font To Fit With \n

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uilabel

So I am trying to get some text to fit
I have used the answer from [Resizing UILabel to fit with Word Wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520855/resizing-uilabel-to-fit-with-word-wrap) to make the text fit. This appears to work except the text is heavily scaled down and only takes up about 50% of the screens width.

This is the code that runs when the view controller is presented:

```
self.user.title = @"Jeffrey C. Louie\n2326 Rockford Road\nCharlestown, MA 02129";
[self.titleLabel setText:self.user.title];

NSInteger fsize = 200;
[self.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:self.titleLabel.font.fontName size:fsize]];

float height = [self.user.title sizeWithFont:self.titleLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.titleLabel.bounds.size.width, 99999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height;

while (height > self.titleLabel.bounds.size.height && height != 0) {
    fsize -=1;
    [self.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:self.titleLabel.font.fontName size:fsize]];
    height = [self.user.title sizeWithFont:self.titleLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.titleLabel.bounds.size.width, 99999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height;
}

for (NSString *word in [self.user.title componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]) {
    float width = [word sizeWithFont:self.titleLabel.font].width;
    while (width > self.titleLabel.bounds.size.width && width != 0) {
        fsize -= 3;
        [self.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:self.titleLabel.font.fontName size:fsize]];
        width = [word sizeWithFont:self.titleLabel.font].width;
    }
}
```

[image: example of text not fitting the view correctly]

It appears to me that the text has been scaled to fit all the text on 1 line as if the hard line breaks did not exist. Is there a way to make the UILabel know there is a line break and scale that rows text accordingly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [RTLabel](https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel) Instead of `UILabel`,
and replace the new line character to `<br>` tag of `html`.
Like:

```
RTLabel *label = [[RTLabel alloc] initWithFrame:/*your frame*/];
NSString htmlText = [yourText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"<br>"];
[label setText:htmlText];
[yourView addSubView:label];
```